# Other users cannot see that an email has been saved in SharePoint

Tags: harmon.ie

According to this page https://harmon.ie/documentation/sharepoint/outlook/savingemail users should be able to see if an email has been archived by a colleague and co-recipient.

Snip from the documentation:
"If your email recipients reside in the same domain, the Saved Location button appears for them when they view an email message you saved to SharePoint. 
Contact your administrator if this option is not available to you. "

How do I activate this feature if it is not available?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have registered the below key, and once you have uploaded the email in Sharepoint with harmon.ie, the “Saved Location” button should appear in the original email in Outlook. If you send such email to another user, the “Saved Location” button should also appear to the user receiving such email.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\SaveConversationInTheSameLocation]
@="true"

----- Jean